# Deleting a Stored API Key for GoogleSpeech

Tags: api

When using `"GoogleSpeech"` in `SpeechSynthesize` for the first time, a window opens asking for the API key. I entered what I thought was my API key and checked the box to save the key. However, I used the wrong key.

Now I get the error message

> "SpeechSynthesize::apierr: The service returned the following error message: API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.."

whenever trying to use GoogleSpeech.

This makes sense, but I cannot determine how to delete that bad, stored API key.  I've done some spelunking in GoogleSpeech.m, and the debugger shows it obtains the bad key at some point. However, I can't determine where it might be stored.

I have also messed around with `PermissionsKey(s)`, `DeletePermissionsKey`, and `SystemCredentialKeys` but still cannot delete the bad key.

Comment: Try running `SystemCredentialKeys[All]`. If the API key for Google Speech is listed, then `Unset[SystemCredential["nameOfKey"]]` should clear it. A more brutal approach would be to run `Unset@*SystemCredential /@ SystemCredentialKeys[All];` and get rid of all saved system credentials, but that may be overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can retrieve your saved service connection to Google Speech with

```
(* Use ServiceConnect to load ServiceConnections` *)
ServiceConnect["GoogleSpeech"]

ServiceConnections`SavedConnections["GoogleSpeech"]
(* {ServiceObject["GoogleSpeech", 
    "ID" -> "connection-5ba85e29a494c940d913da46b18c210b"]} *)
```

Now simply delete this connection with:

```
ServiceConnections`DeleteConnection["GoogleSpeech"]
```

At your next `SpeechSynthesize`, you will be asked for a new API key.

---

Note that, as suggested in the WolframConnector dialog (*You can save connection to your **cloud account** ...*), these credentials are not stored under `SystemCredentialKeys`, but in the Cloud. You can retrieve it with

```
Import[CloudObject["connections/services/GoogleSpeech"], "RawJSON"]
```

Because the authentication is performed via [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), it's not the initial API Key that is stored, but another token that was retrieved during the authentication.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need, and Names["ServiceConnections`"] gives {"ServiceConnections`DeleteConnection", "ServiceConnections`SavedConnections", "ServiceConnections`ServiceConnections"}.

However, ServiceConnections`SavedConnections["GoogleSpeech"] just returns ServiceConnections`SavedConnections["GoogleSpeech"], and the same for DeleteConnection.

Comment: Ah, sorry, `ServiceConnections` is not automatically loaded, so just evaluate one `ServiceConnect["GoogleSpeech"]` in the beginning :)

Comment: I figured there was a Needs or something needed.  Thank you so much for the help.